Application which connects to the Tor Network?
I am looking for a software which would connect to Tor network and open a port (proxy) which other applications can use to get connected to the Tor network.
Requirements:

MacOS
Not a VPN application (Orbot)
Not a Browser. Do not want to increase my memory footprint. (Tor Browser)

In the past we used to have Vidalia (on Windows not sure of Mac) but it's now discontinued.
On Windows I managed to find something similiar but it not available for MacOS.
I have no preference in terms of the UI and for that matter the application can be a headless application as well which runs through the command line and a configuration file. The TorProject website only shows the option of Tor Browser and Orbot.

Download the tor application from here (this link is unfortunately not visible to me if I just browse around https://www.torproject.org).
You can run the tor application from the command line and pass it a torrc file containing your required configuration. The application exposes a SOCKS port at 9050 by default.
The manual of tor for more information.
